# Controlling other effects in a single effect Expression

Tags: javascript, after-effects

I'm not sure how to write this question properly,
the thing is
I want to be able to control two other effects via a single effect like this:

```js
var a=value;
var b=thisLayer.effect("Form")("Y Displace");
var c=thisLayer.effect("Form")("X Displace");
snd=thisComp.layer("Bass").effect("Sound Keys")("Output 1");

if(thisComp.layer("Funcion").effect("On/off Displace")("Slider")==0){
    a=snd*10;
    b=snd*4;
    c=snd*4;
} else {
    a=0;
    b=0;
    c=0;
};
```

The problem is the other Effects (Y Displace and X Displace) don't change,
and the value of this one effect where I'm writing the expression is taking the value of `var c` instead of `var a` as I want it to do.

I need to write an expression in a single effect because I need to copy the same expression to different layers with the same set of effects, and it's quite painful to customize it for every single layer.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot work the way you would like: an expression in a property affects that property and nothing else (the variables a, b, c can refer to some other properties but dont modify their value).

So in the property corresponding to 'a' (you didnt give its name) the expression would be:

```
if(thisComp.layer("Funcion").effect("On/off Displace")("Slider").value==0){
    10*thisComp.layer("Bass").effect("Sound Keys")("Output 1").value;
} else {
    0;
};
```

And in the "Y Displace" property:

```
if(thisComp.layer("Funcion").effect("On/off Displace")("Slider").value==0){
    4*thisComp.layer("Bass").effect("Sound Keys")("Output 1").value;
} else {
    0;
};
```

Etc.

Edit : the reason why you always get case "c" is that After Effects retains the last calculated value (it calculates, a, then b, then c, hence the result is c).